# Angular ng-repeat inside nav tab not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate a nav tab dynamically.

This code works:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(1)}">
           <a ng-click="select(1)" aria-controls="all menu"role="tab">The Menu</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(2)}">
           <a ng-click="select(2)" aria-controls="appetizers" role="tab">Appetizers</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(3)}">
            <a ng-click="select(3)" aria-controls="mains" role="tab">Mains</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(4)}">
            <a  ng-click="select(4)" aria-controls="desserts" role="tab">Desserts</a></li>
  </ul>

               <div class="tab-content">
               <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
                <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in dishes | filter:filtText">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a ui-sref="app.dishdetails({id: dish._id})">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                        ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                        <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{dish.label}}</span>
                        <span class="badge">{{dish.price/100 | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p ng-show="showDetails">{{dish.description}}</p>
                         <button  ng-show="showFavorites" ng-click="addToFavorites(dish._id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right"
                    type="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            </div>
```

Follow the jscode in Menucontroller:

```
  menuFactory.query(
        function (response) {
            $scope.dishes = response;
            $scope.showMenu = true;

        },
        function (response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
        });

    $scope.select = function (setTab) {
        $scope.tab = setTab;

        if (setTab === 2) {
            $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
        } else if (setTab === 3) {
            $scope.filtText = "mains";
        } else if (setTab === 4) {
            $scope.filtText = "dessert";
        } else {
            $scope.filtText = "";
        }
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
        return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
    };
```

Here the code with ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li ng-repeat="category in categories" role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isSelected(category)}">
<a ng-click="select(category)" aria-controls="category" role="tab">{{category}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here new jscode in the controller:

```
 $scope.categories = ["all menu","appetizers","mains","desserts"];

    $scope.select = function (setTab) {
        $scope.tab = setTab;

        if (setTab === "all menu") {
            $scope.filtText = "";
        } else {
            $scope.filtText = setTab;
        }
    };



    $scope.isSelected  = function (category){
       $scope.currentCategory = category;  
    };
```

When I tried with ng-repeat the links in the nav don't work. Previously, I've forgot to replace numbers for strings ( $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {return ($scope.tab === checkTab);}; The function select is now calling. 
I'd like to put the items in an array and generate the nav dynamically from a list of categories. Finally I replace $scope.filtText = "setTab" to  $scope.filtText = setTab and now filtText is working correcty.

Thanks!!

Comment: In the first case, isSelected() and select() take a number as argument (1, 2, 3, 4), and each link has a string as content (The Menu, Appetizers, etc.), whereas in the second, both are replaced by  `category`. `category can't be a number and a string as the same time. But anyway, for more help, indent your code properly, and post your JS code. The code matters.

Comment: Yes - we need the JS code to help you out.

Comment: Thanks! Your clue was great!